# Flutter: unable to show the value for text, using column or row

Tags: flutter, text

can you help me figure whats wrong on my code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget texttest(String){

    Text('hi');
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            texttest(String),
            texttest('hello'),
            texttest('wtf'),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

can you help me figure what wrong? or am i missing something

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Function `TextTest` should return a value, and some other errors have been fixed:

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget TextTest(String text) {
    return Text(text);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextTest('String'),
        TextTest('hello'),
        TextTest('wtf'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

**update**
Maybe what you want:

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  final String greeting;
  Test(this.greeting);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(greeting),
        Text('hello'),
        Text('wtf'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

and use it `Test('Hi')`

Comment: i see now,, but can i put a value inside texttest already and on the other children is to add a value like i did on the top?,, like this Text(''hi") and then on the main build ill just want to change the value to "hello"?

Comment: and to answer the value of String instead String hello wtf,, it should be hi, hello wtf right?

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, i want to understand something. How will i have a value of hi on test if there is no 'hi' on the code. Will it work by typing this.greeting only? Sorry i understand the rest but the this.gretting worries me a little :)

Comment: [Here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) you can read about constructors. ``Test(this.greeting);`` is a shortcut to ``Test(String greeting) { this.greeting = greeting; }``